# Liferay 7 add salesforce jar library error

Tags: salesforce, liferay

I am going to integrate salesforce library into liferay 7 mvc portlet, the following steps are what i did:

1. Add libraries to class path. In Eclipse, go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs, then add the sfdc-wsc JAR to this list
2. Add below line to build.gradle:
   compile group: 'com.force.api', name: 'force-wsc', version: '40.1.1'

The java source code is ok until i use gradle build to build project, the following error occur:

error: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise does not exist import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;

error: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise does not exist import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult;

error: package com.sforce.soap.enterprise does not exist import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.SaveResult;

I also set the bnd file as follow according to blog post of DAVID H NEBINGER: https://web.liferay.com/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies 
But nothing is improved

Bundle-ClassPath:.,\lib/externalLib.jar
-includeresource:\
lib/externalLib.jar=externalLib.jar,\
lib/commons-lang.jar=commons-lang=[0-9]*.jar

Please give any suggestion to correct.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed such a solution, but I used a different approach. I've implemented an OSGi bundle that exports Salesforce's SOAP APIs. This way you can use Salesforce APIs in any other Liferay bundle.

On this [Salesforce SOAP API Client OSGi Bundle](https://github.com/amusarra/salesforce-client-soap) repository you find the sources. The [OSGi bundle](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/it/dontesta/labs/liferay/salesforce/client/soap/salesforce-client-soap/1.0.1/salesforce-client-soap-1.0.1.jar) is also available on Maven Central.

Once you install the Salesforce SOAP API Client OSGi bundle, you can use it in any other Liferay bundle, such as your MVC Portlet. This sample project [Salesforce Liferay Gogo Shell Command Client](https://www.dontesta.it/en/liferay-7-salesforce-com-gogo-shell-command-client) implements a set of Gogo Shell commands that allow us to interact with the Salesforce CRM system.

In your particular case, if you want to include external libraries via Gradle, then you can declare your dependency through the key compileInclude.

```
dependencies {
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
compileOnly group: "org.apache.felix", name: "org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime", version: '1.0.6'
compileInclude group: 'org.fusesource.jansi', name: 'jansi', version: '1.16'
compileInclude 'de.vandermeer:asciitable:0.3.2'}
```

This way you do not have to do anything on the bnd file. The external jar, like magic will be placed inside your bundle and MANIFEST will be correct.

If you want generate your stubs then you go at [Force.com Web Service Connector (WSC)](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but before I read your answer I have do as following:
right click on project -> Gradle -> refresh gradle project

Then the saleforce API library is downloaded to my portlet's external dependencies, it seem be ok. But the remaining error from generated wsdl library , I used follow guide to generate it:

http://usefulliferaytips.blogspot.jp/2014/01/liferay-and-salesforce-integration.html

Can you tell me how can I import that generated wsdl to use in my project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Antonio,

Thanks you very much, I am very sorry that i did not mention the same question was posted on:

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/92741832

Can you give me any ideal about this question?

Looking forward to hear from you.